# In my Shipment Method there is no quotes shown when I select for United Kingdom

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

Here I have posted a image where in shipment method there is no quotes available for united kingdom

Comment: ?? where the images. Suggesting to please check your shipping setting at admin